# bookdown/rmarkdown/knitr: Open a document with the (graphical) result of a later code chunk?

Tags: r-markdown, knitr, bookdown

Imagine a simplified `bookdown`/`rmarkdown` document that goes something like this:

````
---
title: "Test Doc"
author: "Balin"
date: "May 25, 2018"
output: 
  bookdown::pdf_document2:
    toc: no
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

<!-- Placeholder - See question -->

This stands in for an extensive report where `code`, its documentation
and interpretation of its results are integrated:

1. We load some data:
   ```{r data-loading}
    my_data <- cars
   ```

2. We (rougly) explore that data and report on it:
   ```{r data-exploration}
   summary(my_data)
   ```

3. We transform the data:
   ```{r data-transform}
   my_data <- log2(my_data)
   ```

4. ... many, many more steps ...

5. We perform a (central) graphical analysis:
   ```{r data-plot}
   plot(my_data)
   ```

6. We state some interpretation ... etc.
````

In such a report I am aiming to replace the `<!-- Placeholder - See question -->` bit with an "Executive Summary"/"Sneak-Peak" section, that centers on the graphical output of chunk `data-plot`. Is that achievable in `bookdown`/`rmarkdown`/`knitr` while maintaining the `code`/narrative integration given the relative positioning?

Comment: Down voting without a comment - I consider that impolite.

Comment: This is a perfect question in my eyes, and also highly useful. However, to survive on Stack Overflow, [you have to learn to ignore some irresponsible downvoters who don't really know what they are doing](https://yihui.name/en/2018/05/right-easier-than-wrong/). Haters gonna hate, and downvoters gonna downvote.

Comment: Thank you indeed for your soothing words.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use `knitr::fig_chunk()` to dynamically retrieve the path to a figure produced in a specific code chunk, e.g.,

````
---
title: "Test Doc"
author: "Balin"
date: "May 25, 2018"
output: 
  bookdown::pdf_document2:
    toc: no
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

# Executive Summary {-}

Here is an amazing discovery!

![](`r knitr::fig_chunk('data-plot', 'pdf')`)

# Detailed analysis

This stands in for an extensive report where `code`, its documentation
and interpretation of its results are integrated:

1. We load some data:
   ```{r data-loading}
    my_data <- cars
   ```

2. We (rougly) explore that data and report on it:
   ```{r data-exploration}
   summary(my_data)
   ```

3. We transform the data:
   ```{r data-transform}
   my_data <- log2(my_data)
   ```

4. ... many, many more steps ...

5. We perform a (central) graphical analysis:
   ```{r data-plot}
   plot(my_data)
   ```

6. We state some interpretation ... etc.
````

[image: PDF output]

To make this work for other types of output formats, you may need to change the filename extension `pdf`. One way to do it can be:

```
![](`r knitr::fig_chunk('data-plot', if (knitr::is_latex_output()) 'pdf' else 'png')`)
```

Of course, this assumes that you use the `pdf` device for LaTeX/PDF output formats, and use `png` for other formats (which are the default settings for graphical devices in R Markdown).

Comment: Thank you very much @Yihui Xie ! Yet another great detail of your suite of tools! Am I correct in assuming that if I want to be able to compile to both `*.pdf` (via `LaTeX`) and `*.docx`, the file extension must change to `png` in the latter case? Is there an easily queried variable to check what we are compiling towards?

Comment: ... and something else: does it matter whether the plot producing chunk is in a child document?

Comment: It does not matter if it is called in a child document or not. For Word, yes, you need to change the filename extension to `png`. I have updated my answer.

Comment: Outstanding! Thank you very much!

Comment: Is there a way to have `![](`r knitr::fig_chunk('data-plot', if (knitr::is_latex_output()) 'pdf' else 'png')`)` itself embedded into inline code? I want to do something like `r if(thisistrue){cat("the link")}`, but neither cat, nor paste bend to my will ...