# rmarkdown/bookdown: Edit `metadata$abstract` on the fly?

Tags: r, r-markdown, bookdown

This has partially been asked (without any takers) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30120588/2103880) and I have reached out via comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31226698/2103880) - apologies for the multi-pronged approach ...

In my ongoing quest (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50524025/2103880) for the example and further aspects) to automated report assembly using [`bookdown`](https://bookdown.org/), I would like to do the following:

1. Start a paragraph in the `yaml` header like so:

   ````
   ---
   title: "Test Doc"
   author: "Balin"
   date: "May 29, 2018"
   abstract: "Bare bones abstract."
   output: 
     bookdown::pdf_document2:
       toc: no
   ---

   This stands in for an extensive report where `code`, its 
   documentation and interpretation of its results are integrated:

   1. We load some data:
      ```{r data-loading}
       my_data <- cars
       # PLACEHOLDER (see in text below) #
      ```
   <!-- ... -->
   ````
2. As the processing progresses I aim to **edit** the `yaml`-deriving 
   abstract, cumulatively assembling/augmenting it. I know about 
   `rmarkdown::metadata$abstract` (see e.g.
   [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31226698/2103880)), but the
   `metadata` object appears immutable and can't be edited.

   I in essence want to replace the `PLACEHOLDER` bit in the example with 
   something like:

   ```
   rmarkdown::metadata$abstract <- paste(
     rmarkdown::metadata$abstract,
     "The analyzed dataset contains",
     nrow(my_data),
     "data points.")
   ```

   Can that be achieved?

Answer (score 1):

Remember that the YAML doesn't have to be all in one block, or all at the beginning of your Rmarkdown document.

In my Rmarkdown reports I put the abstract in a separate YAML block **after** the analysis.  At that point you can reference R objects as inline expressions as in other Rmarkdown.  The abstract will still be placed a the beginning of the output document.

`````
```{r last_chunk}
# run R code
````

---
abstract: |
On `r Sys.Date()` we analyzed `r nrow(mydata)` observations and found...
----
`````

The only trick - you **must** have empty lines before and after the `---` delimiters for the YAML block to be recognized.

Caveat - I use this in Rmarkdown but haven't tested it with bookdown.